# Got a user agent string from my IIS logs which makes no sense to me. Has anyone else encountered something similar?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I reviewed IIS logs for an issue that was reported to me.

Below are two entries I see:
The initial hit from the user's IP shows user agent as

> Microsoft+Office+Excel+2013

The second hit from the user's IP shows user agent as

> Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.3;+ms-office)

I tried to replicate this by opening the webpage in Excel 2013 by entering URL in the 'Open' option under File menu. Since the webpage requires Cookies and Javascript, it displays the error message I have defined and does not create any entry in the IIS logs.

Has anyone seen something similar or can advise what might be the issue here? and what I can do to replicate and solve this?

Comment: Why do you think this is an issue?

Comment: Agree. Why do you think that the UserAgent is a problem at all? And what's the "issue" you're researching?

Comment: I have a form that allows unique participation. Once the form is submitted, the link expires and shows a custom expiry page. However, this user submitted the form using chrome and then again accessed the form with the user string I mentioned above. Any insight you could provide on this would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Apparently these user agents are being sent over when someone is clicking a link inside an Excel sheet or the now defunct InfoPath.

Still, it is not clear why you are considering these as an issue. The user agent can easily be spoofed and made to contain anything.

Comment: I have a form that allows unique participation. Once the form is submitted, the link expires and shows a custom expiry page. However, this user submitted the form using chrome and then again accessed the form with the user string I mentioned above. Any insight you could provide on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: Maybe you should review your application code and see why the form didn't properly expire after the first submission. I don't see any relation to the user agent.

Comment: The application is being used for years now and I have never had a query like this. I also tried to review the code if there is something that might allow the link to be used again but I think it is something to do with this particular device/approach. If I figure the root cause, I will be able to make required amendment to the code

Comment: Is that form unique per user? If so then the expiration logic is trivial: after the form is submitted, disable it then do stuff with the submitted data.

Comment: There is a unique key that the system generates for each form. This unique key is a part of the URL. Once the key has a submission associated to it, the key is disabled. So I am not sure how the user was able to access the form using a disabled key. The IIS logs clearly show the URL accessed which has the same key for both hits

Comment: How far apart (time wise) are the two submissions?

Comment: The submissions are approximately a 3-4 days apart.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this yourself by any chance? Do you have proof that the key was successfully disabled after the first submission?

Comment: No I was unable to reproduce this issue. Yes, I checked the date/time when the key expired in the DB which seems fine

Comment: Well then I still think there is a bug in the application code. Whether the bug is triggered or influenced by a less known user agent is frankly quite irrelevant - in the end the bug is there. Without seeing the code I can't offer more insights :(

Comment: Not a problem @CyberDude Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the addressed page could be using user agent info for routing old browsers that doesn't support the page. That is how I came here..